# How to allow slashes in Struts 2 Action Names?

Tags: java, struts2

I'm trying to enable slashes in Struts 2 action names. I've put this in my config file:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <constant name="struts.action.extension" value=","/> 
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="2147483648" />
    <constant name="struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value="true"/>

    <package name="myApp" extends="struts-default">                         
        <action name="home" class="net.myapp.actions.HomeAction" method="execute">
            <result name="landing">/landing.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="/ajax/foo" class="net.myApp.actions.ajax.FooAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">/foo.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>        

</struts>
```

When I go to just the homepage of this app, e.g `http://localhost:8034/myApp`, I see the homepage correctly. But if I visit `http://localhost:8034/myApp/ajax/foo`, I get the error: `There is no Action mapped for action name ajax/foo.` even though I have described it above as the 2nd action.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use ajax/foo instead of /ajax/foo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say you need a namespace as well, so `ajax` would be the namespace in your case:

```
<package name="myApp" extends="struts-default" namespace="/ajax">    
  <action name="foo" class="net.myApp.actions.ajax.FooAction" method="execute">
     <result name="success">/foo.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

Note that you could use slashes in your action names, e.g. `foo/bar`, but it's not advisable, since some plugins (e.g. the conversation plugin) might have difficulties to determine the namespace and action from a string like `/ajax/foo/bar`.

Btw, the error message says `There is no Action mapped for action name ajax/foo.`, i.e. struts looks for an action named `ajax/foo` but you only have an action `/ajax/foo`.

Comment: If I do this, then will all my urls need to have 'ajax' in front of them? E.g could I serve `/foo` and `/bar` as well as `ajax/foo` and `ajax/bar`?

Comment: @ClickUpvote you could have multiple packages with different namespaces, e.g. one with namespace `/` for `foo` and `bar` and one with namespace `/ajax` for `ajax/foo` and `ajax/bar`.

Comment: I tried to add a 2nd package: `<package name="ajax" extends="struts-default" namespace="/ajax">` and put the `foo` action inside it (so it should map ajax/foo to it), but I get a null pointer exception whenever I try to visit /ajax/foo or even the homepage (which is in this package: `<package name="myapp" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">`

Comment: @ClickUpvote Where do you get the NPE? What is null?

Comment: No idea. But, after doing a clean and build, it now seems to be working properly. thanks