# In Struts 2 Can Name Attribute of Action Be a Path?

Tags: java, web-applications, configuration, struts2, struts

In Struts 2, can the name attribute of action be a path? By that I mean can it be the following:

```
<action name="/api/method/call" ...>
```

Is there any source that has explained what attributes the action tag in Struts config can have.  Struts seem to be really undocumented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see docs on this section [Action Names](http://struts.apache.org/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-ActionNames). However, it is not the same like yours, because of the leading slash.

> #### Action Names With Slashes
>
> If your action names have slashes in them (for example, 
>   `<action name="admin/home" class="tutorial.Admin"/>`
>   ) you need to specifically
>   allow slashes in your action names via a constant in the `struts.xml`
>   file by specifying 
>   `<constant name = "struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames" value = "true"/>`. See JIRA Issue [WW-1383](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-1383) for discussion as there are
>   side effects to setting this property to `true`.

---

You can remove the leading slash and see if it's working or use a convention plugin with [Action Annotation](http://struts.apache.org/docs/convention-plugin.html#ConventionPlugin-Actionannotation).

> #### Action Annotation
>
> The Convention plugin allows action classes to change the URL that
>   they are mapped to using the `@Action` annotation. This annotation can
>   also be used inside the `@Actions` annotation to allow multiple URLs
>   to map to a single action class. This annotation must be defined on
>   action methods like this:
>
> ```java
> public class HelloWorld extends ActionSupport {
>   @Action("/different/url")
>   public String execute() {
>     return SUCCESS;
>   }
> }
> ```
>
> Our action class will now map to the URL `/different/url` rather than
>   `/hello-world`. If no`@Result` (see next section) is specified, then
>   the namespace of the action will be used as the path to the result, on
>   our last example it would be `/WEB-INF/content/different/url.jsp`.

---

Answer (score 0):

docs link for your reference.

```
https://struts.apache.org/docs/home.html
```

you could use slashes in your action names, but not advisable,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19114364/5086633